# CreationTime generating wrong Date

Tags: powershell

I am checking for whether a file was created recently using the following script:

```
$today = (Get-Date).Date
$file = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | where { $_.CreationTime.Date -eq $today}

if ($fileCreated) {
    Write-Host "`r`n << $file >> generated in [ $((Get-Location).Path) ]"
} else {
    Write-Host "`r`n file NOT generated!"
}
```

This was working flawlessly yesterday.

For some reason now, `$file.CreationTime` outputs everytime

[image: CreationTime]

even though the file is being created at, using `$today`, for example

[image: today]

If I test this:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv
Write-Host ($file.CreationTime.ToString('M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt'))
Write-Host "$file generated in [ $((Get-Location).Path) ]"
```

I get back the file and in the correct location, so I know for sure that the file is being correctly found. however, now the creation time somehow is always this after I added `ToString`.

[image: CreationTimeToString]

I don't understand how is it possible that yesterday the script was working flawlessly and now it suddenly doesn't work anymore as intended ... and what Ican do to get the correct `CreationTime` to match `$today`?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188026/discussion-on-question-by-cataster-creationtime-generating-wrong-date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was happening was because CreationTime is the time the file was created. However, since the file was not getting recreated, in other words, it was just being modified everytime my script supposedly generates the csv file, the creationtime would of course NOT change.

The more appropriate method to use, per @Lee_Dailey's suggestion, is the LastWriteTime property.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | where { $_.LastWriteTime.GetDateTimeFormats()[6] -eq $today}
```